# using the "img" tag with html5

Tags: html

I was once told that the "img" tag in html had to be nested within an element such as the p tag.  Is this true? or was mislead?

```
<p><img src "img/mittromneylittleface.png" alt="drinks" /></p>
```

Comment: you can always use img tag without p tag

Comment: Isnt this something that could be verified on ur own?

Comment: @KevinBoucher You don't even what to know the filename of Obama's picture ..

Comment: Why the down votes? This is a perfectly good question--one I had as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well if you were *once* told that, you were told this in the context of HTML 4.  Take a look at the DTD for HTML 4 Strict [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html).

You will see that `IMG` is an `%inline` element, but the HTML `BODY` element can only contain `%block`, `SCRIPT`, `INS`, and `DEL` elements:

```
<!ELEMENT BODY O O (%block;|SCRIPT)+ +(INS|DEL) -- document body -->

<!ENTITY % block 
   "P | %heading; | %list; | %preformatted; | DL | DIV | NOSCRIPT |
    BLOCKQUOTE | FORM | HR | TABLE | FIELDSET | ADDRESS">
```

So if you want to validate HTML 4 strict, you should definitely include the `IMG` inside a `P` or similar.  Try it on a validator, you will see:

> document type does not allow element "IMG" here; missing one of "P", "H1", "H2", "H3", "H4", "H5", "H6", "DIV", "ADDRESS" start-tag

Now, in HTML 5, you **can** have an `img` element right under the `body` element.  Check out the definition of the `body` element [here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-body-element).  It says the content model for the `body` element is:

> Flow content

If you lookup Flow content, you will see that `img` is allowed!